# Say name of a caller on iPhone

Tags: iphone, contacts

Is there an app, or any other way, to make my iPhone 4 to say the name of the caller while ringing, just the same way we are used to on Nokia phones? Preferable without jailbreak or sophisticated scripting trickery...and preferably a text to speech solution.

Comment: Preferably, it should be a text to speech solution

Answer (score 3):

By default, no.

But it wouldn't be that hard to record the name (or perhaps using the voices in VoiceOver Utility to speak them), [turn that into a ringtone](http://tips.artoftheiphone.com/2009/01/19/how-to-create-an-iphone-ringtone-using-itunes/), and then apply it to the specific contacts you have via the Address Book as a [custom ringtone](http://www.askdavetaylor.com/how_to_assign_custom_ringtone_contact_apple_iphone.html).

It's a bit of legwork, but it's a clean way of doing it and won't require any outside software or hacking of the device.

Answer (score 1):

I know you said Preferably without jailbreak, but if you do there are a few solutions:

[CallTell](http://modmyi.com/cydia/package.php?id=28109) - Announces who's calling before ringing. Text support too.

[iAnnounce](http://modmyi.com/cydia/package.php?id=31091) - Announces incoming calls. iOS4

I personally use CallTell and would happily recommend it.

Answer (score 0):

[Google Voice](https://www.google.com/voice/) has a feature similar to this. It's called [call screening](http://support.google.com/voice/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=115083). The main problem with the feature, though, is that it will probably annoy your callers. Basically every time you get a call from a new number, the caller is asked to say their name. Then when you pick up the phone, you hear their name, and have the option of answering the call or sending it to voicemail.

While it's not exactly what you requested (since you have to answer the phone before you hear who it was that caused the ringing), it does provide a similar solution.